# Mapping a MongoDB document's _id with Vert.x

Tags: spring, mongodb, vert.x

I'm using Vert.x MongoDB client as well as Vert.x CodeGen (https://github.com/vert-x3/vertx-codegen).

This is an example of my document:

```
@DataObject
public class Instrument {

  public static final String DB_TABLE = "instruments";

  private String id;
  private String instrumentId;
  private String name;
}
```

Since the model of my document (or entity) is annotated with `@DataObject`, how can tell Vert.x which field I want to use as Mongo's `_id`?

When using Spring (Data), one can annotate an entity with `@Document` and the field to be used as Mongo's `_id` with the annotation `@Id`. Is this possible in Vert.x?

If not, is there any turnaround?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

for mongoDB you can use http://vertx.io/docs/vertx-mongo-client/java, with http://vertx.io/docs/apidocs/io/vertx/core/json/Json.html to read/write jsonObject or string.